# C# Calculator Cast a Button

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple calculator in .NET C# in Windows Forms Application.

I made this calculator 3 years and now I don't understand some parts of the code and I found a bug.

So, I casted a Button to read the numbers buttons(?) and then I use a Switch in order to know what was the number pressed or operation.

Button b = (Button)sender

It is working. 
The problem is that when i click outside a button (somewhere in the form) it throws a exception.

Any help?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ex8CalculadoraCompleta
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double value = 0;
    string operation = "";
    bool operation_pressed = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_nclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((txt_resultado.Text == "0")||(operation_pressed))
        {
            txt_resultado.Clear();
        }

        operation_pressed = false;
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (b.Text == ",") // Avalia se pode acrescentar outra vírgula/ponto
        {
            if (!txt_resultado.Text.Contains(","))
                txt_resultado.Text = txt_resultado.Text + b.Text;
        }
        else
        txt_resultado.Text = txt_resultado.Text + b.Text;
    }

    private void btn_ce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_resultado.Text = "0"; //L
    }

    private void btn_operatorclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;

        if (value != 0)
        {
            btn_resultado.PerformClick();
            operation_pressed = true;
            operation = b.Text;
            lbl_equation.Text = value + " " + operation;
        }
        else
        {
            operation = b.Text;
            value = Double.Parse(txt_resultado.Text);
            operation_pressed = true;
            lbl_equation.Text = value + " " + operation;
        }  

        //
    }

    private void btn_resultado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_equation.Text = "";

        switch(operation)  //C
        {
            case "+":
                txt_resultado.Text = (value + Double.Parse(txt_resultado.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "-":
                txt_resultado.Text = (value - Double.Parse(txt_resultado.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "*":
                txt_resultado.Text = (value * Double.Parse(txt_resultado.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "/":
                txt_resultado.Text = (value / Double.Parse(txt_resultado.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        } //fim switch

        value = Double.Parse(txt_resultado.Text);  //Convert txt  Double
        operation = "";
    }

    private void btn_c_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_resultado.Text = ""; //L
        value = 0;
        lbl_equation.Text = "";
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 111)
        {
            switch (e.KeyChar.ToString())
            {
                case "0":
                    btn_0.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "1":
                    btn_1.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    btn_2.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    btn_3.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    btn_4.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    btn_5.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    btn_6.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "7":
                    btn_7.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "8":
                    btn_8.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "9":
                    btn_9.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "+":
                    btn_soma.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "-":
                    btn_sub.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    btn_mult.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    btn_div.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "#3Dh":
                    btn_resultado.PerformClick();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Source Code:
https://pastebin.com/p1ggeSz4

exception error is: System.InvalidCastException

```
private void btn_nclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((txt_resultado.Text == "0")||(operation_pressed))
    {
          txt_resultado.Clear();
    }

    operation_pressed = false;
    Button b = (Button)sender;



    if (b.Text == ",") // Avalia se pode acrescentar outra vírgula/ponto
    {
        if (!txt_resultado.Text.Contains(","))
            txt_resultado.Text = txt_resultado.Text + b.Text;
        }

        else
        txt_resultado.Text = txt_resultado.Text + b.Text;
    }
```

Comment: _"it throws a exception."_ We can't see it! Please add message and stacktrace.

Comment: What exception it throws? You have so many click methods, how do we guess which of those is the one throwing exception

Comment: Button b = (Button)sender;
will throw an exception if the casting failed, so casting this way should only be used when you expect the casting to always succeed.
If you instead write:
    Button b = sender as Button;
The variable b will be null if the casting failed, so you can handle it like:
    if(b == null) return;

Comment: It might be as simple as mistakenly assigning a handler to an event it's not meant for, like form.click since you said clicking somewhere else on the form throws the exception.

Comment: System.InvalidCastException  on btn_nclick

Comment: Sir JokesALot thanks. it worked!!

Comment: @LooksPerfect Great! I wrote it as an answer, please accept it.

Comment: Not at all "perfect" @SirJokesALot The Exception is a symptom for the handler to be registered with an event it is not meant to be registered with. Simply muting the error doesn't make it go away. If you fix all your errors like this, it will sooner than later blow up in your face ... you really need to find the actual cause.

Comment: @Fildor You are right. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button b = (Button)sender;` will throw an exception if the casting failed, so casting this way should only be used when you expect the casting to always succeed. If you instead write:
 `Button b = sender as Button;` The variable b will be null if the casting failed, so you can handle it like:
 `if(b == null) return;`

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Ignoring exceptions like this to provide workable code is not good.  I suspect the event handler was assigned to the wrong event...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it thanks to user! 
Thank you all.
That's how it looks:

```
Button b = sender as Button;
if (b == null)
{
     return;
}
```

Comment: Hm, isn't the point that clicking anywhere but on a button should _not_ trigger that event handler? The above code surely works but most probably only hides a totally different mistake. (Such as registering the handler with an event it is not meant for) Mind that your "operation_pressed" flag will still be reset for example.

Comment: How am I supposed to do then?

Comment: 1. Surround the cast with try/catch. 2. Place a breakpoint in the catch clause. 3. Run debugger and produce the exception. Then you will be able to see, what the sender type is. So you get a hint who raised the event. Then find out where the handler is wrongly registered and remove that registration. Then recheck that this fixed the problem. Then you can remove the try/catch again.

Comment: Alternatively, if you already implemented the suggested "fix". You can set a breakpoint on the `return` in `if(b==null)`

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Can not bind object of type 'Calculadora.Form1' to the type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'.'

Comment: Right. So you most probably registered Form1's Click event to the handler that throws the exception. That should be easy to check.

Comment: Yes I have                                                                                               private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)